# Validator.js - How to validate Alphanumeric password, in NodeJS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, validation, express

I am using [criso validator.js](https://github.com/chriso/validator.js/), of user Input,

but it Eslint is showing error in syntax on this lines

```
if (!Validator.isAlphanumeric([(data.password,'en-US')])) {
    console.log(" Not an alphanumeric");
  }
```

how to properly check user's entered password is Alphanumeric,

I know we can do it using regex but I wanted to do it by using their provided syntax as `isAlphanumeric(str [, locale])`.

here is their documentation screenshot of code.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Why only alpha numeric? The hash algorithm used for hashing the password will work the same way with or without "special" characters.

Comment: There's excessive square brackets. Correct one should be like this `Validator.isAlphanumeric(data.password,'en-US')` I think

Comment: Forcing passwords to be alphanumeric just makes them weaker. It is a really bad idea.

Comment: @Andrey is right. Also you should consider [password-validator](https://github.com/tarunbatra/password-validator) for password validation rules.

Comment: @Andrey, your solution worked. but the same answer is given by Romellem.. , after your comment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The square brackets in the `isAlphanumeric(str [, locale])` notation are **not** related to [JavaScript Array literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array). Instead, they denote that when calling `isAlphanumeric`, the first argument `str` (in your case, `data.password`) is *required*, and the second argument `locale` is *optional*.

In your case, you do want to pass in a `locale`. Here is how that would look:

```
if (!Validator.isAlphanumeric(data.password, 'en-US')) {
    console.log("Not an alphanumeric");
}
```

In technical documentation, square brackets (`[]`) generally denote that an argument is optional. Tecnhnically this is just a convention (and probably comes from Unix CLI [Usage Messages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Usage_message#Pattern)), but in my experience is so widely used that always interpreting square brackets as denoting an optional argument is usually a safe assumption to make.

Comment: thanks but the comment from Andrey, solved my issue. so it's upvoted. :D

Comment: it seems, to be working. but I am using it in my nodejs app and and If it's not `alphanumeric ` then It should not work, but it worked and registered user and didn't print to console as `Not an alphanumeric`, my github link for code is https://github.com/ganeshdeshmukh1612/connect-geeks/commits/master and main file where I used this logic is here https://github.com/ganeshdeshmukh1612/connect-geeks/commit/fe62bc82a9830bbd8b6b6bfebe59b8e4762b1d26#diff-d832326d3a8f15e682c27e9b3165dcf7

Comment: or should I add this, in main question?

Comment: @ganeshdeshmukh that is a different issue. Your original question is essentially "When I call `Validator.isAlphanumeric([(data.password,'en-US')])` I receive an error," and that because you were not calling the `isAlphanumeric` function correctly. Now that you've corrected this implementation error, it looks like the overall functionality you want to achieve isn't working, but that would be a separate issue from your original post. So, I would not edit your post above, and instead ask another question.